# Как сделать так чтобы дата выводилась именно та которую я ввожу в переменную time TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Bishkek' Например ввожу 12:00:00 а получаю 06:00

Tags: python, django

И если кто то шарит как правильно сделать функцию резервирования(reservation, reservations) не особо понимаю.

````
class Reservation(models.Model):
    computer_club = models.ForeignKey('clubs.Club', models.CASCADE, related_name='club_reservation', null=True)
    seats = models.ForeignKey('clubs.Table', models.CASCADE, related_name='seats_reservation', null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='owner_reservation', null=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField('Введите время бронирования')
    time1 = models.DateTimeField('Время окончания бронирования', blank=True)
    using_time = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Введите на сколько часов вы садитесь')
    #reservation = models.IntegerField('Количество броней за день')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Бронирование'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Бронирование'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.computer_club } {self.seats } {self.time } {self.using_time } {self.time1 } {self.owner }'




    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        time = self.time
        time += timedelta(hours=self.using_time)
        self.time1 = time
        super(Reservation, self).save()

    def reservations(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for i in self.reservation:
          if self.owner.i == Reservation:
            i += 1
            if self.owner.i == 5:
              print('Невозможно сделать больше 5 бронирований в день')
            
        super(Reservation, self)
        
    def reservation(self, *args, **kwargs):
        while True:
          if self.using_time == 0:
            print('Ошибка!')
            continue
          else:
            print('Бронь успешна')
            break
    reservation(using_time)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В admin.py пропишите

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Reservation


class ReservationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['pk', 'computer_club', 'seats', 'time', 'using_time', 'time1', 'owner' ]

admin.site.register(Reservation, ReservationAdmin)
```